# Find the next iteration in loop python

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I am trying to find out if given a string if 2 target characters follow one another. So essentially, I am trying to find if a character and its neighbor are target characters. How should I go about this? The following is what I have tried so far.

```
target_list=["t","a","r","g","e","t"]

for char in some_string:
    if (char and some_string[some_string.index(char)+1]) in target_list:
        print ("correct")
    else:
        print ("incorrect")
```

Expected output:

1. if some_string="heytr" == "correct"
2. if some_string="hyt" == "incorrect"
3. if some_string="heyt" == "incorrect"

Answer (score 1):

Just go through the indices and process every pair of characters:

```
for i in range(len(some_string) - 1):
    if some_string[i] in target_list and some_string[i+1] in target_list:
        print ("correct")
        break

if i == len(some_string) - 1:
    print ("incorrect")
```

You can alternatively create a mapping and look for adjacent true positives:

```
m = [(char in target_list) for char in some_string]

for i in range(len(m) - 1):
    if m[i] and m[i+1]:
        print ("correct")
        break
if i == len(m) - 1:
    print ("incorrect")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import tee

def rolling_window(iterable, n=2):
    iterators = tee(iterable, n)
    for i, iterator in enumerate(iterators):
        for skip in range(i):
            next(iterator, None)
    return zip(*iterators)

def match(some_string, target, n=2):
    target = set(target)
    return any(target.issuperset(s) for s in rolling_window(some_string, n=n))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use map:

```
    target_list=['t','a','r','g','e']

def toDict(list):
    mp  = {}
    for c in list:
        mp[c] = True
    return mp

d = toDict(target_list)

print("dict:" , d)    

def check(string, mp):
    count = 0
    for c in string:
        if(mp.get(c,False)):
            count = count+1
            if(count > 1):
                return True
        else:
            count = 0   
    return False


print("check:" , check("heytr", d))       
print("check:" , check("hyt", d))    
print("check:" , check("heyt", d))
```

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression solution.

```
import re

target_chars='target'

p = re.compile('[%s]{2}' % re.escape(target_chars))
m = p.search(some_string)
if m:
    print('correct')
else:
    print('incorrect')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#any) and [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) for this:

```
target_list=["t","a","r","g","e","t"]

target_list = set(target_list)

some_strings = ["heytr", "hyt", "heyt"]

def match_strings(string, target_list):
    return any(x in target_list and y in target_list for x, y in zip(string, string[1:]))

for some_string in some_strings:
    if match_strings(some_string, target_list):
        print("correct")
    else:
        print("incorrect")
```

Which Outputs:

```
correct
incorrect
incorrect
```

**Logic of above code**:

- Converts `target_list` to a set, since set lookup is constant time. If you keep it as a list, then lookup time is linear.
- Uses `zip()` to create pairs of the current element and the next element, and checks if both of these elements exist in `target_list`. Then checks if `any()` of the pairs exist, which returns `True` if any of the pairs exist, and `False` if none exist.
- Then loop over all the strings in `some_strings`, and check the above for each one.

Answer (score -1):

```
def judge(some_string):
for index in range(0,len(some_string)-1):
    if some_string[index] in target_list and some_string[index+1] in target_list:
        print("correct")
        break
else:
    print("incorrect")

judge("heytr") --correct
judge("hyt") -- incorrect
judge("heyt") --incorrect
```

For loop iterates on all character of the string checks if i and i+1 is present in target.if yes prints out correct. after all iterations of loop is over if no two character are found in target it comes to the else part of for loop and prints out incorrect.

Comment: While this code-only answer may answer the question, please add an explanation of why it does so. This will help future users evaluate the answer for their situation.

Comment: Hi ggo, tom - I am new to stackovrflw. Thanks for the suggestion.I will do it from next time,